# Dynamical instability and thermal instability

Tags: astrophysics, stars, stellar-evolution

I'm studying instability in Stellar Dynamics (in particular globular clusters instabilities).
I have not understood clearly the definition of these concept.

Dynamical instability is the study of the instability considering an adiabatic process: we perturb the system and see what happens.
Thermal instability happens at much larger timescale than the dynamical one and is due to the exchange of energy between single stars (and since the thermal capacity of the system is negative, this process brings phenomena like the gravothermal catastrophe).

Am I missing something?